# Pod unable to mount same path in two volumes

Tags: kubernetes, mounted-volumes

I am a newbie here , but I have a use case where I need to mount same path to two different PV's , When ever I try to give the same path my pod doesn't come up check mount paths below

```
  - name : xxx
    mountPath : "/home/{username}"
    readOnly : false
static:
  pvcName:
  subPath: '{username}'
capacity: 10Gi
homeMountPath: '/home/{username}'
dynamic:
  storageClass: nfs-client
  pvcNameTemplate: claim-{username}{servername}
  volumeNameTemplate: volume-{username}{servername}
  storageAccessModes: [ReadWriteOnce]
```

But after changing the mount path pod comes up without any issue example

```
mountPath : "/home/test/{username}"
```

Is there something I am missing

Comment: PV are global spaced, so once a pod consumes the volume using PVC it doesn't allow the same volume to be used by other as overwriting is not allowed

Comment: I am using different PVC to claim different PV

Comment: Can you include a more complete example, and the actual error message you're getting (maybe from `kubectl describe pod`)?  That YAML fragment doesn't look like part of a Kubernetes pod spec.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to mount the Single POD with multiple PVC it wont possible unless you use the ReadWiteMany.

But if you want to mount multiple path to POD it's possible using single PVC or multiple PVC depends on use case.

Single PVC single POD

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-test-pod
spec:
    containers:
    - name: mysql
      image: mysql
      env:
      - name: MYSQL_HOST
        value: "IP"
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
        name: data
        subPath: path1
    - name: nginx
      image: nginx
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /var/www/html
        name: data
        subPath: path2
    volumes:
    - name: data
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: my-site-data
```

Multiple PVC and volume path to single POD

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-pod
spec:
  volumes:
    # List of volumes
    - name: volume1
      < volume details, see below >
    - name: volume2
      < volume details, see below >

  containers:
    - name: mycontainer
      volumeMounts:
        # Path
        # will mount 'volume1' into /var/www/html
        - name: volume1
          mountPath: /var/www/html
        # will mount 'volume2' into /var/log
        - name: volume2
          mountPath: /var/log/
```

Reference : https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux_atomic_host/7/html/getting_started_with_kubernetes/get_started_provisioning_storage_in_kubernetes#example